# check if LTE/GSM signaling procedure is right

Tags: python, expert-system, lte, signaling

Here is a need, want to write a tool for checking LTE/GSM/WCDMA signalling procedure is processed according 3gpp spec, and the tool will help protocol developer troubleshooting issues.

1/ it should be have more flexibility, because we cannot add all spec logic into config, the config will added.

2/ the config file have business logic. so I donot know whether have some pattern for this logic.

3/ the tool have some few like expert system, it read config logic, and have some reasoning, and derive the result.

Thx

Comment: I see that you have a need. But what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, my question is I donot know which pattern I should use and whether there exist a pattern to achieve this logic. Thx